# Update multiple keys in json data in same query

Tags: postgresql

I have the following query:

```
UPDATE events e
SET  
   details = jsonb_set ( details, '{"data", "user_name"}', '"Resident"' ),
   details = jsonb_set ( details, '{"data", "is_by_support"}', '"false"' ),
   details = jsonb_set ( details, '{"data", "is_by_resident"}', '"true"' ),
    updated_by = 1,
    updated_on = now ()
FROM
    test_req tr
WHERE
e.id = 12345 AND
    AND e.data_reference_id = tr.id
    AND e.event_type_id = 4
    AND e.created_by = 2
    AND e.updated_by = 2
    AND e.details -> 'data' ->> 'user_name' = 'Test'
    AND e.details -> 'data' ->> 'is_by_support' = 'true'
    AND e.details -> 'data' ->> 'is_by_resident' = 'false';
```

After executing it gives me an error as

```
ERROR:  multiple assignments to same column "details"
```

How to use multiple keys update in the same query? Is there any other way?

Comment: Actually, test_req has a few columns that are in common with the events table. For the generic question, I skipped those conditions in the where clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have the same column several times in the `SET` clause of an `UPDATE`. Why not do something like

```
SET details = jsonb_set(
                 jsonb_set(
                    jsonb_set(
                       details,
                       '{"data", "user_name"}',
                       '"Resident"'
                    ),
                    '{"data", "is_by_support"}',
                    '"false"'
                 ),
                 '{"data", "is_by_resident"}',
                 '"true"'
              )
```

Comment: With your solution, it only updates user_name but did not work for the other two that are is_by_support and is_by_resident. For them, values are still the same.

Comment: I find that hard to believe.

Comment: It works Thanks Laurenz. Due to some trigger its not getting updated.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
WITH list AS
(  
SELECT e.id, jsonb_set(
                     jsonb_set(
                        jsonb_set(
                           details,
                           '{"data", "user_name"}',
                           '"Resident"'
                        ),
                        '{"data", "is_by_support"}',
                        '"false"'
                     ),
                     '{"data", "is_by_resident"}',
                     '"true"'
                  ) AS sol
FROM events e
INNER JOIN test_req tr
ON e.data_reference_id = tr.id
    WHERE e.id = 12345
        AND e.event_type_id = 4
        AND e.created_by = 2
        AND e.updated_by = 2
        AND e.details -> 'data' ->> 'user_name' = 'Test'
        AND e.details -> 'data' ->> 'is_by_support' = 'true'
        AND e.details -> 'data' ->> 'is_by_resident' = 'false'
)
UPDATE events e
SET details = l.sol,
    updated_by = 1,
    updated_on = now ()
    FROM list AS l
WHERE e.id = l.id
```