# Using MyBatis mapper.xml to increment a multiple counters in the same query inside of a JSONB field in Postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, database-design, mybatis, jsonb

I am working with Java + Spring + MyBatis + Postgresql. I have a table with a `JSONB` column in which there are a series of `BIGINT` (which are mapped to `Long` in Java), that for performance reason I want to update using a query inside of the `mapper.xml` relative to the entity the attribute belongs to.

Supposing that I the following elements:

- `table_a`: a database table
- `column_1`: column of `table_a` of type `JSONB`
- `key_alpha`: field of `column_1` associated to a `BIGINT` value

Ideally in pure `psql` syntax I would do the following to initialize such value:

```sql
UPDATE table_a
SET column_1 = jsonb_set(column_1, '{key_alpha}', to_jsonb(0));
```

And the following to increment it:

```sql
UPDATE table_a
SET column_1 = jsonb_set(column_1, '{key_alpha}', to_jsonb((column_1->>'key_alpha')::bigint + 1));
```

The problem is that it looks like that this syntax is not compatible with MyBatis `xml` mapper syntax. How can I achieve this result using MyBatis, or by using an alternative method, while keeping in mind that I need a performance-critical approach?

More specifically, if I try to use this syntax in the `mapper.xml`:

```
<if test="incrementCountAlpha != null">column_1 = jsonb_set(column_1, '{key_alpha}', to_jsonb((column_1->>'key_alpha')::bigint + #{incrementCount})),</if>

<if test="incrementCountBeta != null">column_1 = jsonb_set(column_1, '{key_beta}', to_jsonb((column_1->>'key_beta')::bigint + #{incrementCount})),</if>
```

I get the following error; `### Error updating database.  Cause: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: multiple assignments to same column "column_1"`

Comment: It worked for me. What exactly happens? If there is an error, please add the details to the question.

Comment: @ave I updated the body of the question with the specific error I am getting

Comment: That error occurs when the column `column_1` appears twice in a single UPDATE statement. See this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69671051/1261766). To update multiple fields of a JSONB column, there seem to be several different solutions. This [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38884555/1261766) looks popular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following statement should achieve your goal.

```xml
<update id="updateColumn1">
  update table_a set column_1 = column_1
  <if test="incrementCountAlpha != null">
    || jsonb_build_object(
      'key_alpha',
      coalesce((column_1->>'key_alpha')::bigint, 0) + #{incrementCountAlpha})
  </if>
  <if test="incrementCountBeta != null">
    || jsonb_build_object(
      'key_beta',
      coalesce((column_1->>'key_beta')::bigint, 0) + #{incrementCountBeta})
  </if>
</update>
```

`COALESCE` might be unnecessary if the target field is guaranteed to be initialized beforehand.

Here is an executable demo project:
https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-77490757